# Scala - Assigning annotation value from configuration file

Tags: scala, cassandra, annotations, datastax

I'm developing an application which interacts with Cassandra using the datastax driver.
Models configuration is done using the @Table annotation.
I have different keySpaces for testing/development/qa/production which are defined in a configuration file.
I'm trying to use the annotation as follows:

**@Table(keyspace = CassandraConfiguration.keySpace , name = "someName")**

When CassandraConfiguration is an object with the following declaration:
**final val keySpace = ConfigFactory.load().getString("dbConnection.keySpace")**

I'm getting the following compilation error:
annotation argument needs to be a constant; found ..CassandraConfiguration.keySpace

How can I set the value to be depended on the environment I am working at ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that was sufficient for my scenario:
declaring an implicit value in a trait which my model extends containing the keyspace has solved the problem.
**implicit val keySpace = KeySpace(config.getString("dbConnection.keySpace"))**